# Create Interval of Years and extract repeated value

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a table similar to this:

| Name | Year |
| --- | --- |
| Name1 | 1950 |
| Name2 | 1951 |
| Name3 | 1952 |
| Name4 | 1953 |
| ...... | .... |
| Name7 | 2019 |
| Name3 | 2020 |
| Name9 | 2021 |

And I have to extract the name that repeats in all decades (every 10 years) from the minimum date to the maximum date.

I'm trying to do groupby, but I just can't get the result I want.

The groupby is as follows:

```
data.groupby('Year').Name.nunique().reset_index()
```

The problem is that this groupby groups the years individually for me and I want to extract the names of the people who repeat every 10 years.

What could be the way to extract this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this will be creating a temporary column which will have decades, and then grouping by that column:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["Name1","Name2","Name2","Name1","Name3","Name3"], 
    "Year": [1950,1951,1952,1960,1961,1961]
})

df['Decade'] = (df['Year']//10)*10
counts = df.groupby(['Decade'])['Name'].value_counts()\
            .rename('Counts').reset_index()
```

Which gives us:

```
    Decade  Name    Counts
0   1950    Name2   2
1   1950    Name1   1
2   1960    Name3   2
3   1960    Name1   1
```